# How to fit different screen size

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

My app looks good on iphone, elements cover all screen but in ipad they cover only half of the screen.
How can I fit size depending on size devices?

Comment: Use adaptive layout and constraint for different sizes.

Comment: How could I do it?

Comment: You can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272850/universal-layout-vs-different-iphone-ipad-storyboards and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012284/how-to-set-up-different-auto-layout-constraints-for-different-screen-sizes

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you can add different constraints depending on the device size. However a well defined layout should work well across all screens.

Apple documentation is always a great place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1